# Can I re create user authentication by phone number in firebase after being deleted?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I Saw videos on youtube that shows users has been deleted whether manual in firebase console or programmatically by the user also alert will be received that "user it can't be recovered". However, after deleting the same user has been recreated again, How can I recreate authentication user by phone number after delete user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to generate a user profile with the same UID as before you deleted it, that is not possible. The user can sign in with the same credentials, but that will create a new user profile, with a new UID.

Comment: yes, exactly that is what I mean, How to generate sign in user profile UID?

Comment: For the built-in providers: you don't control what UID to create for a new user. And as said: after deleting a user, there is no way to recreate that same UID. It might be easier to help further if you describe the actual problem, instead of how you're thinking to solve it. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).